# How to rename folder so that it sort folders with date prefix with name in windows?

Tags: windows, directory

[screenshot of folders with prefix with date [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDVNc.png)]

As attached image,I want to know how to rename a folder so that it will sort date wise with postfix any string?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question right you could try setting the date as yyyymmdd eg 20180525 for today, if that works for you.